# XNA - Error while rendering a texture to a 2D render target via SpriteBatch

Tags: xna, c#, post-processing, bloom

I've got this simple code that uses `SpriteBatch` to draw a texture onto a `RenderTarget2D`:

```
private void drawScene(GameTime g)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(skyColor);
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(targetScene);
    drawSunAndMoon();
    effect.Fog = true;
    GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(line);
    effect.MainEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
    GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, 0, 2);
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
    SceneTexture = targetScene;
}

private void drawPostProcessing(GameTime g)
{
    effect.SceneTexture = SceneTexture;
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(targetBloom);
    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Opaque, null, null, null);
    {
        if (Bloom) effect.BlurEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
        spriteBatch.Draw(
            targetScene,
            new Rectangle(0, 0, Window.ClientBounds.Width, Window.ClientBounds.Height),
            Color.White);
    }
    spriteBatch.End();
    BloomTexture = targetBloom;
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
}
```

Both methods are called from my `Draw(GameTime gameTime)` function. First `drawScene` is called, then `drawPostProcessing` is called.

The thing is, when I run this code I get an error on the `spriteBatch.Draw` call:

> The render target must not be set on the device when it is used as a texture.

I already found the solution, which is to draw the actual render target (`targetScene`) to the texture so it doesn't create a reference to the loaded render target.

However, to my knowledge, the only way of doing this is to write:

```
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(outputTarget)
SpriteBatch.Draw(inputTarget, ...)
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null)
```

Which encounters the same exact problem I'm having right now.

So, the question I'm asking is: how would I render `inputTarget` to `outputTarget` without reference issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `targetScene` and `targetBloom` are the same texture. You should check you're not assigning one to the other somewhere in your code. Or maybe, your `spriteBatch` is using the same texture you're using as a render target (`targetBloom`); you just can't do that (that's a hardware limitation).

I know your question is about how to fix your fix, but I don't understand what you're trying to do, and I see no reason why your first solution wouldn't work.

Comment: OH, just as I read that everything just clicked into understanding. Yeah, targetScene and targetBloom were the same. I was initializing them via:
`targetScene = targetBloom = new RenderTarget2D(...)`